# Downloading binary from MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

Suppose binary file (e.g. PDF) exists in MarkLogic,
which REST API could be used to request direct downloading the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GET /v1/documents](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents) .

Comment: In case you'd like to open the url in a browser and not have it show the binary directly, but open a file save dialog instead, you can do that by adding a content-disposition header. Here is a rest transform that does that, though you can probably achieve it with a few lines of xqy too: https://github.com/marklogic-community/slush-marklogic-node/blob/master/app/templates/rest-api/transforms/download.xsl